# Función Martes13 pgadmin

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, pgadmin

estoy repasando las funciones pero no consigo resolver esta;

Escribe una función que devuelva todos los martes 13 durante un año especifico.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM martes13(2020);

13/02/2020
13/03/2020
13/12/2020
```

Un ejemplo de lo que he intentado.

```
DECLARE

diaInicial date;
diaFinal date;
anio1 date;
anio2 date;
auxData date;
dates date[];

BEGIN

diaInicial := ('01/' || '01/' || anio ) :: date;
diaFinal := diaInicial + '1 YEAR' :: interval;
anio2:= date_part('year',diaFinal);

FOR i IN 1..12 BY 1 LOOP
 FOR j IN 1..30 BY 1 LOOP
   diaInicial := anio || '-' || i || '-' || j;
   if(date_part('dom',auxData)==13 and date_part('dow',auxData)==5)then
      dates[j] := diaInicial;
   end if;
 end loop;
end loop;
return dates;
END;
```

No hay forma de resolverlo por mas que lo intento, entiendo que tengo que usar dates, anios intervalos y contadores pero no me sale.
Cualquier ayuda o dato podría servirme.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Algo habrás intentado... por favor, muéstranos tus intentos para hacernos una idea de en qué podemos ayudarte

Comment: Ahí una de las cosas que he intentado, @DavidJP

Comment: Has pensado en que solo necesitas evaluar 12 fechas? Solo el día 13 de cada mes.

Answer (score 0):

La primer regla para programar en bases de datos es no tratar de decirle al motor como hacer las cosas sino decirle que es lo que quieres. Los motores de base de datos saben hacer bucles para recorrer tablas de manera muy eficiente y eso se debe de aprovechar. Así, lo que debes de tratar de regresar cuando hay varios posibles valores es un conjunto de datos o de resultados.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( anio || '-' || n || '-' || 13, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Fecha
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))t(n) --Puedes tener esto como una tabla fija o calcularlo cada vez
WHERE EXTRACT( dow FROM TO_TIMESTAMP( anio || '-' || n || '-' || 13, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = 2; --evalua si el día de la semana es 2(martes)
```